# server control onclick error

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, runtime-error, servercontrols

I am using a datalist inside which I have defined an itemtemplate. I am using asp:LinkButton inside this itemtemplate. I have used an OnClick="methodname" in this linkbutton tag. I have the corresponding mehtodname defined in my code behind, However I keep getting  a Java runtime error when the page loads up and when I click on any of the items in the datalist. It says that I have not javascript function function defined with the name mentioned.

Isnt asp:LinkButton a server control. I want to use my c# code behind and not javascript. How do  I proceed??

`<asp:DataList ID="DLID" RepeatColumns="5"
         RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server"`>

`<ItemTemplate`>
                        `<div class="home"`>
                    `<div class="homeblock"`>`</div`>
                              `<div class="homeitem"`>
                                                `<ul`>`<li`>`<span style="font-size:small;"`>
                                                `<asp:LinkButton ID="TopItem" runat="server" OnClick="Item_OnClick"`>`<%# Container.DataItem %`>`</asp:LinkButton`>
                                                `</span`>`</li`>`</ul`>
                             `</div`>
                     `</div`>
                `</ItemTemplate`>
     `</asp:DataList`>

Comment: post more code. also post rendered output.

Comment: Mix up between OnClick and OnClientClick? We really need more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works perfectly fine for me. Used your markup code minus the class names. Here is the code-behind I used:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        string[] ds = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g" };
        DLID.DataSource = ds;
        DLID.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void Item_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

What is the exact error message?

Comment: this works now. Thanks for the simplified code! Also I need to bind a string to an asp:label control. I need to actually to bind it to the string that is selected by user from the "TopItem" linkbutton control. How can I do this?  `<asp:Label ID="Item" runat="server" Text="<%# Container.DataItem %>"`>`</asp:Label`> Can I bind this asp:label control to a string? Or do i have to use a diferent control to achieve this?

Comment: I just solved this in my code behind by  setting the label's text property to my string value that I extract in the onclick event. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Just put the C# code/logic in the asp:LinkButton Click Event.